# How do you create a composite foreign key when key being referenced is also a foreign key

Tags: sql-server

If you have table `a` (column `x`) which is 1 to many with table `b` (columns `x`, `y`) which is 1 to many with table `c` (columns `y`, `z`), it's pretty straight forward to define the foreign keys.

If for performance reasons, table `c` was altered to be (columns `x`, `y`, `z`) is there a way to specify that table c (columns `x`, `y`) have a foreign key relationship to table `b`'s (columns `x`, `y`)?

Previously table `c` contained 2 single column foreign keys `x` --> table `a` and `y` --> table `b`.  While this is correct, it creates erroneous results when trying to use commercial tools to create database diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no problems:

```
create table a(x int primary key);
create table b(x int references a, y int, primary key(x,y));
create table c(x int, y int, z int, foreign key(x,y) references b);
```

Comment: i'll try that.  x is not a primary key in b right now.

Comment: Post the DDL statements of your tables.

Comment: thanks.  that worked.  my mistake was not including both columns in the primary key for the intermediate table.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a composite foreign key from `B` to `C`:

```
alter table TableC
     add constraint FK_TableC_XY
     foreign key (x, y)
     references TableB (x, y)
```

That's better than two foreign keys: this will ensure that the combination of `(x, y)` is present, and not just the individual values.

Comment: actually, thats what i want to do but sql server will not let me because table b (x) has already been declared as a foreign key from table a (x).

Comment: as a follow on to the question which would be higher performing: a composite key which can be validated from one table or two foreign keys which can be validated from two different tables.